# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory in Intellij, scala project with playframework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have generated scala project imported to intellij by exposed dbt-model. In console test run fine but in intellij java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, more boring:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at play.api.Logger$.<init>(Logger.scala:182)
at play.api.Logger$.<clinit>(Logger.scala)
at play.api.Application$class.$init$(Application.scala:272)
at play.api.test.FakeApplication.<init>(Fakes.scala:221)
at play.api.test.WithApplication$.$lessinit$greater$default$1(Specs.scala:20)
at UserTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$1.<init>(UserTest.scala:10)
at UserTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(UserTest.scala:10)
at UserTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(UserTest.scala:10)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
```

sj4j is attached to intellij by sbt. Where is the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just included a dependency on SLF4J API, but you must also include an implementation that does the real logging work.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.10"
```

I recommend you to use logback-classic:

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"
```

The version may be incorrect.

Comment: It is the solution. I had gos 1.0.9 and it was the problem. The numbers related to scala version  are magic still.

Comment: The version numbers really come from package developer. Sometimes, a package may need a new API in a specific version of Scala. So you really need that version of Scala.